# CSS expand DIV and push others down

Tags: css, html

I have a stack of DIVs.  With in those divs are expandable jquery panels, placed with in those divs.  When the Panel expands, if it is larger than the div it is contained in I want it to expand.  I have been trying the endless suggestions here, but there is something wrong with my CSS.  Thank you for any help.  I'm wondering if it's my position: absolute.  I need the top and left attributes to be locked in but the divs can expand down, I would just like them to push the ones below themselves down as well.

```
#framecontent{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0; 
        left: 0;
        width: 815px; /*Width of frame div*/
        height: 600px;
        overflow: auto; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
        overflow-x: hidden;
        background-image: url('../images/Bkgrnd.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-x; 
}


#listcontainer{
        position:absolute;
        width: 260px;
        margin-top: 70px;
        margin-left:40px;
}

/* Main Header */
#headercontent{
        position:absolute;
        background: #3e3e3e;
        top:0px;
        height: 65px;
        width: 615px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 200px;
}

#subheading1 {      
        position: absolute;
        background: #585858;
        top: 65px;
        height: 45px;
        width: 615px;
        left: 200px;
        color:#ffffff;
}

#response{
        position: absolute;
        background: #585858;
        top: 110px;
        min-height: 115px;
        width: 615px;
        left: 200px;
        color:#ffffff;
        /* box-shadow:inset 5px 5px 2px  #000000;  */
}

#subheading2 {      
        position: absolute;
        background: #313131;
        top: 225px;
        height: 45px;
        width: 615px;
        left: 200px;
        color:#ffffff;
}

#summary {
        position: absolute;
        background:  #454545;
        top: 270px;
        height: 375px;
        width: 615px;
        left: 200px;


}
```

Comment: Could you paste an example of the div's and the css in here and the click run? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Not related, but #headercontent has two position properties. I would say it is something to do with absolute positioning, or the fact that everything on your page seems to have a set width and height, which means it won't expand

Comment: As stated above, put your html, css and jQuery into http://jsfiddle.net/ and maybe we can see better what's going wrong.

Comment: Yeah getting rid of the absolute positioning and using margins helped.  I'm stuck on a expandable jquery pane with in one of the divs and when I expand it, I want the div to expand.  Maybe I should look in the CSS for the expando panel.  Thank you all for your help

Comment: I got rid of height and that fixed the expanding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all position:absolute from your CSS. Then, if you want align it with others, you can use margin, padding, and float...

Please provide more details of your HTML file, I can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to say what your html does, when you only present a piece of css.

But from what you show it looks to me like a positioning problem. Take the position absolute out of your css and look what happens then.